# Using lastRow in a range for a change function

Tags: excel, vba

First thing's first, here's the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$T$3" Then
   Range("BY3:BY & lastRow").Value = "Please Select..."
   Range("BX3").Value = "Please Select..."
   Range("AC3").Value = "Please Select..."
   Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = Range("A:BZ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  End If
End Sub
```

My goal is that every time any cell in column T (not just cell $T$3) is changed, then column BY, BX, and AC, will all be changed starting at row 3, down to the last used row.

How can I achieve this?
Currently, I'm receiving the following error:

[image]

I'm pretty sure I'm far off, but I appreciate the help!

Comment: This line (`Range("BY3:BY & lastRow").Value`) is wrong for two reasons. First, your `lastrow` variable is inside quotes which means its being interpreted as is and second, even if your variable was outside of the quotes, you have not yet defined `lastrow` which means it will default to `0`

Answer (score 0):

### A couple of things....

1. Use `Intersect` to check to see if the changed cell (`Target`) overlaps (`Intersect`) with `Column T`
2. When using a variable range, the variable must be outside of the quotes. Anything inside quotes is read literally. Your current method is referring to a row that does not exist: *error*
3. You must assign your last row (`lr`) variable before you reference it. Otherwise, it will default to `0`. Since this row also does not exist: *error*
4. Don't use `Dim lr as Integer` - just use `Long` which is best practice. `Integer` does not cover the amount of available rows in excel making this error prone. `Long` is the minimal/complete variable to use which covers any possible row input.

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lr As Long

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("T:T")) Is Nothing Then
    lr = Range("BZ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      Range("BY3:BY" & lr).Value = "Please Select..."
      Range("BX3:BX" & lr).Value = "Please Select..."
      Range("AC3:AC" & lr).Value = "Please Select..."
End If

End Sub
```